# tkinter - remove border / padding from gif button / label

Tags: python, tkinter

I know there is a lot of info related to this question, but I cannot get any of it to work with my specific situation.

I'm trying to create a tkinter button menu out of gifs and I want these gifs to be flush up against one another, no border, no spacing. I've been able to achieve this with a regular button, but not with a button with an image file. I've attempted this with labels and there is no "border", but I still cant get rid of the padding, even after setting the relevant attributes to "0".

I'm aware of both the "bd" and the "highlightthickness" attributes and I'm pretty sure that the highlightthickness attribute is specific to the canvas widget, but I could be wrong? Either way, i've put it just about anywhere I can think and I still have this annoying border.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I'm a newbie to python and tkinter, but relatively comfortable with coding. This seems almost as straightforward as html tables, etc, but ive spent a couple nights scouring the internet and I can't find any answers, let alone any example of an image based button menu without spacing issues.

Apologies again for the newbie-ness of this dilemma. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

---

code example using "Label" widget:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.wm_title("Window Title")
root.config(background = "#FFFFFF")

leftFrame = Frame(root, width=600, height = 800, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
leftFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)

try:
    imageEx = PhotoImage(file = 'nav1.gif')
    imageEx2 = PhotoImage(file = 'nav2.gif')

    Label(leftFrame, image=imageEx).grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)
    Label(leftFrame, image=imageEx2).grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=0)

except:
    print("Image not found")

root.mainloop()
```

---

code example using "Button" widget:

```
import Tkinter as tk

button_flag = True

def click():
    global button_flag
    if button_flag:
        button1.config(bg="white")
        button_flag = False
    else:
        button1.config(bg="green")
        button_flag = True

root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
photo1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="nav1.gif")
button1 = tk.Button(frame1, compound=tk.TOP, width=320, height=55, image=photo1,
    text="", bg='green', command=click, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
button1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=0, pady=0)
button1.image = photo1


frame2 = tk.Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)
photo2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="nav2.gif")
button2 = tk.Button(frame2, compound=tk.TOP, width=320, height=55, image=photo2,
    text="", bg='green', command=click, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
button2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=0, pady=0)
button2.image = photo2


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"I'm pretty sure that the highlightthickness attribute is specific to the canvas widget,"_ - no, most widgets have that attribute.

Comment: In the first example you are setting neither the borderwidth or highlightthickness to zero.

Comment: ok i must be confused then, where would i set those if not within the frame specs?

Comment: Set it when you create the label: `Label(leftFrame, image=imageEx, borderwidth=0, highlightthickness=0)`

Comment: thanks bryan, turns out the border issue was a style issue on osx, everything looks fine on debian .. thanks!